# Removing nested dict items with dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, compression

I have two dicts:

```
blocked = {'-5.00': ['121', '381']}
all_odds = {'-5.00': '{"121":[1.85,1.85],"381":[2.18,1.73],"16":[2.18,1.61],"18":\
            [2.12,1.79]}'}
```

I want to first check whether the `.keys()` comparision (`==`) returns `True`, here it does (both `-5.00`) then I want to remove all items from `all_odds` that has the key listed in `blocked.values()` .

For the above it should result in:

```
all_odds_final = {'-5.00': '{"16":[2.18,1.61],"18": [2.12,1.79]}'}
```

I tried `for loop`:

```
if blocked.keys() == all_odds.keys():
    for value in blocked.values():
        for v in value:
            for val in all_odds.values():
                val = eval(val)
                if val.has_key(v):
                    del val[v]
```

which you know is very ugly plus it's not working properly yet.

Comment: You meant to have a nested dict and not a string, correct?

Comment: But, you seem to be using `eval` which means you want that to be a string? Please edit your question accordingly. :)

Comment: I evaluated a nested dict to be a dict after for loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the string a dictionary with [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). [Don't use `eval()`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html):

```
>>> import ast
>>> all_odds['-5.00'] = ast.literal_eval(all_odds['-5.00'])
```

Then you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> if blocked.keys() == all_odds.keys():
...     print {blocked.keys()[0] : {k:v for k, v in all_odds.values()[0].iteritems() if k not in blocked.values()[0]}}
... 
{'-5.00': {'18': [2.12, 1.79], '16': [2.18, 1.61]}}
```

But if you want the value of `-5.00` as a string...

```
>>> {blocked.keys()[0]:str({k: v for k, v in all_odds.values()[0].iteritems() if k not in blocked.values()[0]})}
{'-5.00': "{'18': [2.12, 1.79], '16': [2.18, 1.61]}"}
```

Comment: Clean and beautiful. Thanks for `ast.literal_eval` hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do the same in about 2 lines. I'm not going to use ast, or eval here, but you can add that if you want to use that.

```
>>> blocked = {'-5.00': ['121', '381']}
>>> all_odds = {'-5.00': {'121':[1.85,1.85],'381':[2.18,1.73],'16':[2.18,1.61],'18':\
...      [2.12,1.79]}}
>>> bkeys = [k for k in all_odds.keys() if k in blocked.keys()]
>>> all_odds_final = {pk: {k:v for k,v in all_odds.get(pk).items() if k not in blocked.get(pk)} for pk in bkeys}
>>> all_odds_final
{'-5.00': {'18': [2.12, 1.79], '16': [2.18, 1.61]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
blocked = {'-5.00': ['121', '381']}
all_odds = {'-5.00': {"121":[1.85,1.85],"381":[2.18,1.73],"16":[2.18,1.61],"18":\
        [2.12,1.79]}}
all_odds_final = dict(all_odds)
for key, blocks in blocked.iteritems():
    map(all_odds_final[key].pop,blocks,[])
```

If you do not want to copy the dictionary, you can just pop items out of the original all_odds dictionary:

```
for key, blocks in blocked.iteritems():
    map(all_odds[key].pop,blocks,[])
```

The empty list in the map function is so pop gets called with None as it's second argument.  Without it pop only gets one argument and will return an error if the key is not present.